# Jade & Bootstrap-Datepicker & Inline Button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pug, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a [bootstrap-datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), I'm using the `range` version of it, and, to the right I'd like to add a `button` to make it possible for the user to refresh the query once they've changed the dates.

I've tried identation and some `inline-block` styling but It wouldn't work. The `button` appears but the whole thing messes up.
Here's the example `datepicker` with the `button` not being placed as intended.

```
.input-group.date
        #datepicker.input-daterange.input-group
            input#StartDate.input-sm.form-control(type='text', name='start', placeholder='Date 1')
            span.input-group-addon to
            input#EndDate.input-sm.form-control(type='text', name='end', placeholder='Date 2')
            button.btn.btn-default.btn-sm(type='button', style='margin-left:8px;')
                     i.fa.fa-refresh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you wrapped the button like so:

```
.input-group.date
    #datepicker.input-daterange.input-group
        input#StartDate.input-sm.form-control(type='text', name='start', placeholder='Date 1')
        span.input-group-addon to
        input#EndDate.input-sm.form-control(type='text', name='end', placeholder='Date 2')
        span.input-group-btn
            button.btn.btn-default.btn-sm(type='button', style='margin-left:8px;')
                 i.fa.fa-refresh
```

See: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons

Comment: Thank you! Now I know about the class`input-group-btn`.